# Распарсить список со списками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем добрый день! Есть примерно такой список:

```
my_list = [
           ['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966], 
           ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054],
           ['Customer', 945030, 7715110841, 8163],
           ['Properties', 2000000, 42231762430928, 21115881],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 7769275332, 8221],
          ]
```

Нужно получить такие списки:

```
event_1 = [
           ['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966], 
           ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054],
          ]

event_2 = [
           ['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966], 
           ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054],
          ]
```

Немного поясню - количество методов ('Customer', 'Properties' etc) может отличаться от события к событию, поэтому срезом решить проблему не получается. Отсчитывать новый список нужно всегда от 'Customer'. Как можно проще всего это сделать?

Comment: Список пополам?

Comment: не совсем, количество методов может отличаться, т. е. длина списков может 3 и 4, 5 и 3 и т. д.

Comment: То есть начинается с Customer и до следующего Customer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_list = [
           ['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966], 
           ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054],
           ['Customer', 945030, 7715110841, 8163],
           ['Properties', 2000000, 42231762430928, 21115881],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 7769275332, 8221],
          ]

event_list = []

for l in my_list:
    if l[0] == 'Customer':
        event = []
        event_list.append(event)
    event.append(l)

for e in event_list:
    print(e)
```

Результат:

```
[['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966], ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261], ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054]]
[['Customer', 945030, 7715110841, 8163], ['Properties', 2000000, 42231762430928, 21115881], ['Scenario', 945030, 7769275332, 8221]]
```

Comment: Да, вот так отлично, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
my_list = [
           ['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966], 
           ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054],
           ['Customer', 111111, 7715110841, 8163],
           ['Properties', 2000000, 42231762430928, 21115881],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 7769275332, 8221],
           ['Customer', 2222222, 7715110841, 8163],
           ['Properties', 2000000, 42231762430928, 21115881],
           ['Scenario', 945030, 7769275332, 8221],
          ]

all_lists = [] #будет хранить все списки

for element in my_list:
    if element[0] == 'Customer':
        temp_list = []
        all_lists.append(temp_list)
        temp_list.append(element)
    else:
        temp_list.append(element)

print(all_lists)
```

Comment: Вы проверяли результат? ;)  Намёк - temp_list указывает на один и тот же список на каждой итерации цикла :)  Но в целом почти правильно

Comment: Можете проверить так например id(all_lists[0]) == id(all_lists[1])

Comment: Да, точно, исправлено

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_event(list_: list):
    yield list_.pop(0)
    while list_ and list_[0][0] != 'Customer':
        yield list_.pop(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = [
        ['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966],
        ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261],
        ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054],
        ['Event_time', 456465, 4565456, 45555],
        ['Customer', 945030, 7715110841, 8163],
        ['Properties', 2000000, 42231762430928, 21115881],
        ['Scenario', 945030, 7769275332, 8221],
    ]

    res_list = []
    while my_list:
        res_list.append(list(get_event(my_list)))

    print(res_list)
# [[['Customer', 945030, 8474017318, 8966], ['Properties', 1999999, 40190503687123, 20095261], ['Scenario', 945030, 8556799367, 9054], ['Event_time', 456465, 4565456, 45555]], [['Customer', 945030, 7715110841, 8163], ['Properties', 2000000, 42231762430928, 21115881], ['Scenario', 945030, 7769275332, 8221]]]
```

Comment: Судя по комментариям к вопросу, там не фиксированное количество элементов, поэтому нельзя просто делать срезы, надо искать ключевое слово.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо за замечание.